# Tensorflow - pad tensor with unknown shape

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I'm trying to pad a tensor with unknown shape (but fixed rank) to a fixed shape in my Keras model. The tensor is of type `string`, so I cannot use `tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences` or `tf.image.pad_to_bounding_box`.

I want to use `tf.pad`, but the problem is that I don't know the shape of the tensor, so I have to dynamically compute the padding length. How can I do that?

My current approach is like this, which doesn't work:

```py
def pad_to_length(t: tf.Tensor, target_length: int):
    return tf.pad(t, [0, target_length-t.shape[0]], 'REFLECT')
```

Because `t` can have dynamic shape, `t.shape` will be `(None,)`, so I got the error:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'`

Comment: could u please provide an example where u use your function?

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic shape `tf.shape` instead of static shape `.shape` like

```py
def pad_to_length(t: tf.Tensor, target_length: int):
    return tf.pad(t, [[0, target_length - tf.shape(t)[0]]], 'REFLECT')
```

for tensors `t` of rank 1.